# using django to play a media file from harddisk

Tags: django, html

In my `django` app,I have a `playmedia.html` page in which `html5 video element` is used to play a media file(`video or mp3 audio`).As a first step ,I put the media files in `/home/me/django/myapp/media/audio` folder and hardcoded the src attribute of `<video>`

```
<video id="vid" width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
           <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}audio/candle.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />       
</video>
```

settings file has

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/django/myapp/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

By this setup,when page is loaded,the `html5 video player` in the page shows that the mp3 file is loaded(In chrome ,a blue bar is shown) and I am able to play the audiofile using the `player` ..I would like to select an mp3 file from `local filesystem` and make the `html5 video` play it.How should I go about this?

Suppose I have a test.mp3 in the directory `/home/me/music/`
If I set the src="/home/me/music/test.mp3" ,the player shows up without the file loaded.No blue bar this time.
Also,the server outputs

```
[10/May/2012 08:38:48] "GET /home/me/music/test.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 2191
```

I think this may be because django doesn't know about the path `/home/me/music/` since it is not in the context.

Can somebody help me figure out how this could be done?

Comment: If you check the player with, for instance firebug, whats the url of the mp3 file? I think its an url problem.

Comment: In firebug it is given as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/me/music/test.mp3`

Comment: ..Previously ,when the file was in `{{MEDIA_URL}}/audio` path ,firebug showed url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/audio/test.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

It's not about django at all, it's about webserver which is serving media files (okay, it can be django's dev server sometimes). So you need to "tell" webserver where to find these files How? Depends on the server. For django [it's in urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/), for big servers - in config files.

Also, there is no easy way to say "server my entire local filesystem, please" because of security. You have lots of private information in your files and users from outside should not have access to it at all.